# Apply new master page in Team Site and Wiki Site - MOSS 2007

Tags: 2007, wiki, team

I'm trying to customize the layout of the Team Sites and Wiki site in MOSS 2007.
The idea is to brand it to the client's needs.

I'm thinking in applying new master pages to both of them, but how can this be achieved? I don't want to touch the default.master...

Any ideas would be great.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to look at this too:
http://www.novolocus.com/2008/10/30/feature-receiver-to-apply-master-pages/

It copes with Meeting Workspaces too.

Comment: Hi Andy! Good posts ;) Thx!

Answer (score 1):

All the masterpages are on the library http://yoursite/_catalogs/masterpage/Forms/AllItems.aspx.
There, you can download de default.master, edit it and carge the now master page with another name.

Later, on the http://yoursite/_Layouts/ChangeSiteMasterPage.aspx adress you can assign your new masterpage, also you can assign a masterpage only for a subsite on this url adress
http://yoursite/yoursubsite/_Layouts/ChangeSiteMasterPage.aspx.

Just remember you must validate and aprove the new masterpage.master file before using it

I hope this might help you!

Regards

Charlie

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here. it might help:

http://www.heathersolomon.com/blog/archive/2007/01/26/6153.aspx